# node.js express route: Certain route does not work & undefined routes work

Tags: node.js, express

```js
// routes/index.js

const router = require('express').Router();

...

router.use('/super', require('./super'));


module.exports = router;
```

```js
// routes/super/index.js

const router = require("express").Router();
const Song = require('../../../../models/Song');

router.use("*", require("../../../middlewares/auth"));

router
  .use("*", ({ user: { role } }, res, next) => {
    console.log(role);

    if (role !== 9) {
      return res.status(404).send(); // secret path
    } else {
      next();
    }
  })
  .get("/front", (req, res) => {
    // It doesn't work!
    console.log("work!");
    res.json({ test: "test" });
  })
  .get("/", ({ query: { keyword } }, res) => {
    // It works.
    Song.find(...querys)
      .then(docs => {
        res.json(docs);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        ...
      });
  })
  .patch("/:songID/tag", ({ params: { songID }, body: { value } }, res) => {
    // It works.
  })
  .patch("/:songID/rate", ({ params: { songID }, body: { value } }, res) => {
    // It works.
  })
  .patch("/:songID/title", ({ params: { songID }, body: { value } }, res) => {
    // It works.
  });

module.exports = router;
```

There are 2 problems.

1. Every route (both get and patch) works except `get '/front.'`

   `get '/front'` responds null but 200 and every middleware is ignored.
2. Routes that I never defined respond 200 just like `get '/front'`.

   `get '/back'` is not defined but responds 200.

I think there's going to be a little mistake, but I can't find it.
Of course, any feedback outside the question is also welcome.

Thanks

Comment: How did your call these APIs?

Comment: @lx1412 XMLHttpRequests with Axios from web browsers. I also tried it with Insomnia.

Comment: @lx1412 yes. only `get` requests respond with status 200

Comment: `.get("/", ({ query: { keyword } }, res) => {
    // It works.
  })` matchs `/super/back`, you'd better post more code of `routes/super/index.js`

Comment: @lx1412 I added the code. When I request `/super/back`,  the code inside the callback doesn't run.

Comment: Your sub-router `routes/super/index.js` add a middleware by `get('/',...)`, so the middleware matches all `get` requests with url begins with `/super/`.If the middleware not called, check your `auth` middleware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a reason.
It's so simple that I'm embarrassed.

The file `routes/index.js` has an endpoint `GET /:artist/:title`.

The endpoint is bound before `router.use('/super', require('./super'))`.

So, when I request `GET super/back`, the callback of `GET /:artist/:title` run.

That means my server tries to find a song sung by 'super'.

There is no singer named 'super' in my database.

Therefore, I got null with status 200.

Answer (score 0):

try to put next() outside of the else function. please show how you execute them in insomnia/postman too. following convention of express, use